# Where are the core service timeouts configured?

Tags: core-service, configuration

I am executing a heavy query on a Tridion 2011 SP1 system via the core service via http. After a minute, I get the following message:

> Exception calling "GetListXml" with "2" argument(s): The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59:9730000. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request, or increase the SendTimeout value on the binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."

When I look in `WebUI/WebRoot/Web.config`, I can see in the `configuration/system.serviceModel/bindings/webHttpBinding/binding` that  `sendTimeout="00:05:00"`

This makes me wonder whether I'm looking at the right timeout setting - as the times don't match, presumably not, I suppose. Where else should I be looking for a timeout? Are there any known timeouts that default to 60 seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried increasing the SendTimeout of your local (client side) binding, rather than the setting you found on the server? Default is [1 minute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361(v=vs.110).aspx), which would seem to match your exception. Code & XML config examples available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks David. Indeed it was on the client. Luckily this setting is supported in the Tridion-CoreService powershell module. You can modify it with Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings -ConnectionSendTimeout "00:05:00" or similar